# leaflet coloring images using ImageOverlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, maps

i use leaflet and images files to create some maps.
i use this leaflet [plugin](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#imageoverlay) for ImageOverlay and if i follow manual then work fine.

here code example :

```
var imageUrl = 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
    imageBounds = [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]];
L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
```

my question is how to coloring this image with some easy way ?any idea how to do ?

thanks

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think you can't do something like that.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Giving the ability to the user painting/coloring the image? Or just make the image appear colored?

Comment: @treecon the second image appear colored